# fluentd - When a specific value can be used as a key but not recoded

Tags: fluentd

In the example below,
i can use $ ["kubernetes"]["aaa"]["bbb"] as the key value,

but It cannot be used as a tag value.
$ {recode ["kubernetes"]["aaa"]["bbb"]} also doesn't work.

How can I use it as a tag ??

Why is it so different?

```
  <match **>
    @type rewrite_tag_filter
    <rule>
      key $["kubernetes"]["aaa"]["bbb"]
      pattern ".*"
      tag ${recode["kubernetes"]["aaa"]["bbb"]}
    </rule>
   </match>
```

Comment: Can you try something like this?. `pattern "(.*)"` and `tag $1`.

Comment: I was stupid.
I solved it that way.

Comment: Cool. Let me put it as answer with more explanation!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your regex pattern within grouping brackets `()` then entire matching text can be used the first group result.

Example - 
Expression - `(.*)` 
Matching Text - **Some Text** 
Group 1 - **Some Text**

So using above, below will be your updated fluentd conf.

```
<match **>
 @type rewrite_tag_filter
 <rule>
  key $["kubernetes"]["aaa"]["bbb"]
  pattern "(.*)"
  tag $1
 </rule>
</match>
```